# Cauchy Distribution used in error term in simulation

Tags: regression, simulation, cauchy-distribution

What is the reason used Cauchy distribution in error term for simulation of data. I see a lot of researcher used the distribution but does not stated the reason why used Cauchy Distribution.

Comment: Researchers might do it for any number of reasons. I could mention several reasons but none of them might apply to the particular bits of research you have seen. Which ones were you looking at that used it?

Comment: what i mean is in simulation of linear regression, other than using normal distribution for error in simulation, they used Cauchy distribution also. Why Cauchy distribution also can be used as error in linear regression.

Comment: Again: Researchers might do it for any number of reasons. I could mention several reasons but none of them might apply to the particular bits of research you have seen. Which ones were you looking at that used it?

Comment: I want to Cauchy Distribution in my simulation to create artificial data when the error term is not normal. But my problem is i cannot justify why i want to used Cauchy Distribution in my simulation because i just follow previous research.

Comment: If you don't know why they used Cauchy you shouldn't use it just because they did... we are not mind readers so we cannot tell why it was used by someone in some research.

Comment: @bbadyalina That (doing something because someone else did) seems a poor reason to do something. If we knew what papers you're looking at we might have some chance of guessing why they did it.

Answer (score 3):

A possible explanation is that the Cauchy distribution has symmetric heavy tails https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-tailed_distribution. Thus, it can be a good choice to generate data with possible outliers to assess robustness properties of the investigated methods.

Comment: what is heavy tails. i am not very familiar with the term.

Comment: @bbadyalina The tail of the distribution stands for its graph for large (in absolute value) $x$. Roughy speaking, heavy tail distributions are distributions for which the value of the density for large $x$ is not so small compared to e.g. a normal distribution so that large $x$ are not so much unlikely.